# Ignore ValidateAntiForgeryToken only for specific action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

for security reasons, i prefer to add the attribute ValidateAntiForgeryToken on top of my baseController so all the actions will be affected from that attribute.

I would like to disable that attribute only for single action.

not deriving for my baseController is not an option.
unfortunately, ValidateAntiForgeryToken atribute is sealed class so i can't create my own customValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute based on the original ValidateAntiForgeryToken one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's true that the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` class is sealed but it's not rocket science to roll our own:

```
public class MyValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute: FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate();
    }
}
```

Now of course all that's left in our implementation is to add some check from the filterContext whether the current action is decorated with some custom `ExcludeFromAntiForgeryValidation` attribute and not call the `Validate` method.

Something along the lines of:

```
public class MyValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute: FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        bool shouldValidate = !filterContext
            .ActionDescriptor
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ExcludeFromAntiForgeryValidationAttribute), true)
            .Any();
        if (shouldValidate)
        {
            System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate();
        }
    }
}
```

and then just write a custom attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class ExcludeFromAntiForgeryValidationAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

that you would use to decorate your controller actions with for which you want to exclude antiforgery validation:

```
[HttpPost]
[ExcludeFromAntiForgeryValidation]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: an index is a post?

Comment: Someone mind explaining how this is different than `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]`?

Answer (score 26):

You can disable the validation of anti-forgery tokens for an action by applying the **[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]**
attribute to a method.

```
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
public IActionResult MyFunction()
```

Comment: I'm seeing this as an option if you're using ASP.NET Core, but what about .NET Framework?

Comment: this is not working, i have Added Antiforgery token validation on startup level and now trying to ignore for some of the actions but each time it is going for validation of Antiforgery

Comment: It applies to all asp.net core versions. I think you miss something that would override this attribute.  If you added Mvc filter to check Antiforgerytoken for every action globally with services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute()));
It should work as intended. I use global filters and using the attribute of [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken] for specific actions to ignore check.